# How to loop ansible variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-cli

i have the below yml file which is working as expected

```
---
- hosts: local
- name: Example of provisioning servers
hosts: 127.0.0.1
connection: local
tasks:
- name: Modify security group
  local_action:
    module: ec2_group
    name: ansible_trail
    description: Modify SG Rules
    region: us-east-1
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 22
        to_port: 22
        cidr_ip: 198.168.45.23
    purge_rules: true*
```

i want to repeat the same action for all of my security groups how to do that in ansible  .

instead of assigning the name: optv5_ansible_trail i want to get the value from list or file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but I'll give it a shot.  You probably want to use `with_items`: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops

I'll take a stab and say you might want something like this:

```
tasks:
  - name: Modify security group
    local_action:
      module: ec2_group
      name: "{{ item }}"
      description: Modify SG Rules
      region: us-east-1
      rules:
        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 22
          to_port: 22
          cidr_ip: 198.168.45.23
      purge_rules: true*
    with_items: "{{ security_groups }}"
```

Where `security_groups` is a list of the names of the security groups.  This will call the `local_action` task one time for each item in the `security_groups` list, with `item` as the current item in the iteration.

You can also use more complex data structures and access them with dot notation (e.g. `item.name`, if `security_groups` was a list of dictionaries that had the key `name`).

Comment: Thanks Dan for your help if i include the below code into the code i am getting the error.                                                                               with_items:
           - optv5_ansible_trail
           - ansible_trail

Comment: Try with_items: security_groups without the braces and quotes. It may depend on what version of ansible you are on.

Answer (score 0):

What Dan said will work, but in case you don't want to use a variable file and just add/remove something as a one time operation to all your security groups you can also specify the names directly:

```
tasks:
  - name: Modify security group
    local_action:
      module: ec2_group
      name: "{{ item }}"
      description: Modify SG Rules
      region: us-east-1
      rules:
        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 22
          to_port: 22
          cidr_ip: 198.168.45.23
      purge_rules: true*
    with_items:
      - name-1
      - name-2
      - name-3
```